# Converting a specific ISO8601 TimeSpan ("P2M2W5D") to a C# TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, xml-parsing, iso8601

I've been parsing ISO8601 TimeSpan values for a while now, until I encountered one that caused my code to throw a System.FormatException:

```
TimeSpan ts = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P2M2W5D");
```

Looking at the [ISO8601 Standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), it seems to be a correct input, and also without any ambiguities (the M clearly refers to months, not minutes).

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233033
Message=The string 'P2M2W5D' is not a valid TimeSpan value.
Source=System.Xml
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan.aspx)

> Parameters
>
> s
>       Type: System.String
>
> The string to convert. The string format must conform to the **W3C XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes** recommendation for duration.

And [Duration section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration)

> The lexical representation for duration is the [ISO 8601] extended
>   format `PnYn MnDTnH nMnS`, where `nY` represents the number of years, `nM`
>   the number of months, `nD` the number of days, `'T'` is the date/time
>   separator, `nH` the number of hours, `nM` the number of minutes and `nS` the
>   number of seconds.

From [ISO 8601 Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats)

> In the lexical format for duration the following characters are also
>   used as designators and appear as themselves in lexical formats:
>
> - P -- is used as the time duration designator, preceding a data element representing a given duration of time.
> - Y -- follows the number of years in a time duration.
> - M -- follows the number of months or minutes in a time duration.
> - D -- follows the number of days in a time duration.
> - H -- follows the number of hours in a time duration.
> - S -- follows the number of seconds in a time duration.

As far as I can see, there is no `W` as a duration format in XML specification.

This works for example;

```
TimeSpan ts = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P2M5D");
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`TimeSpan` can not handle this because of the months being specified.  `TimeSpan` is just a number of ticks.  Since the number of days in a month varies it cannot be converted to a tick.

The other issue is that 'W' (week) is defined in ISO 8601 but not in the XML spec, so XmlConvert doesn't know about it.